# How do I generate random numbers in a microcontroller efficiently?

Tags: random, microcontroller

How do I generate random numbers in a microcontroller efficiently? Are there any general guidelines or a particular fast method?

Comment: How much randomness do you need? Is speed the top desire here, or is non-predictability most important? There are many different algorithms for pseudo-random number generation aimed at different applications with different goals. A game, for instance, would not need non-predictability quite as much as say, something generating high-security encryption codes.

Comment: I need speed. There is no cryptographic requirement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can generate *pseudorandom* numbers by manipulation of bits by simulating a **LINEAR FEEDBACK SHIFT REGISTER**

The question then becomes 'how many bits do you want to simulate?'

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LFSR) has some information.

Comment: Each time microcontroller is reset, I'll get same set random numbers. How can I avoid that? In other words, how can I set random seed?

Comment: No real time clock on your controller? That can act as a seed.

Comment: We have a RTC but it is a project-wise decision not to use that. We simulate RTC by firmware. Thanks for the comment. The firmware's second counter can be used as seed.

Comment: Chosen as best answer because I found LFSR is least time consuming to implement and it is also fast. I'm using static value to use as seed because our devices will hardly be reset. When reset occurs, it doesn't matter if it produces same random numbers. The seed value 0xAC gives a period of more than 10^8.

Comment: Picking the right seed for the right bit pattern will give you a maximal LFSR, which will generate all numbers in the bit pattern except for 0.

Answer (score 11):

One normally generates pseudo-random numbers and not actual random numbers, although both are possible at varying rates.

There are two general categories, depending on whether the sequence will be used for cryptographic purposes. The primary distinction is whether knowledge of one number in the sequence allows prediction of the next. General purpose RNG's don't worry about whether knowledge of the algorithm would allow an observer to duplicate the sequence, and they run quite a bit faster.

A typical general purpose RNG algorithm is the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister). There are many public implementations of various algorithms. [See here](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/MT2002/emt19937ar.html) for one.

If the MT requires too much memory, a half-way-decent fallback is the [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). (The MT wasn't invented until 1997.) This generator has certain issues but it requires almost no memory, almost no code, and is extremely fast. Implementations are everywhere, and it was covered in detail in Knuth's *Seminumerical Algorithms*.

To seed any RNG, you will need a source of entropy, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(computing) (Note: SO gets confused about the ()'s in that link.) This is typically derived by timing events that the CPU can observe, such as keystrokes, (I guess that won't work for you) interrupts, and packet arrivals. A real time clock is often an acceptable source if it maintains its own state, as reboots are rarely timed in any sort of sequence.

Comment: These RNG's need a seed to work. Each time the microcontroller is reset, I'll get same set of random numbers.

Comment: Aha, good question. (We get basic RNG questions here on SO all the time so forgive us for reflexively firing out the basic answer. :-) Anyway, I've updated my answer. I'll do another update in a minute...

Comment: Mersenne Twister uses a state space that is too big for microcontrollers.

Comment: Most microcontrollers have ADCs that can be used as entropy sources.  Keep only the least significant noisy bits.

Comment: Almost any decent stream cipher can also be used as a RNG, e.g [Salsa20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20) (or any of the other [eSTREAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESTREAM) ciphers) (seeding remains an issue...) (Memory requirements are likely impractical for most 8-bit devices)

Answer (score 9):

you can store a seed to EEPROM, and when device boots, you can increment a seed and store it again. So, every reboot youll have different random number.

Comment: I dont think thats a very good approach. If it goes in practical application then there will be big cybersecurity issues.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to an ADC, then you can read the least significant bit from it, and use it as a seed for a Pseudo Random Number Generator, like others have posted. Obviously you will need to read more than one bit from the ADC, so multiple reads are needed, which could take a while. But you only need to do this once, at startup for example, and then use faster PRNG to generate new random numbers.

Many embeded devices have built inn ADC, for example the ATMega family form Atmel.

Comment: Unfortunately the ADC in ATMegas is too stable.  Even the LSB doesn't change over many readings.  http://skemman.is/stream/get/1946/10689/25845/1/ardrand.pdf "We explore various methods to extract true randomness from
the micro-controller and conclude that it should not be used to produce
randomness from its analog pins."

Answer (score 3):

If the hardware has a button for the user, a simple trick is to count how long the button is pressed. With a fast enough short counter you get a "random" number.

Comment: Do you know of any estimates of the number of bits of entropy, given a counter speed of 'x' Hz?

Comment: Sorry, no. I guess someone smart could figure that out.

Comment: This is a good solution but in my case I need the random number far before user interaction takes place (actually, as soon as micro gets power). Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo random number generators that are the fastest and least demanding w.r.t. the instruction set (only shift and xor, no multiplication or division) are smaller variants of the Mersenne twister idea (called Generalized Linear Feedback Shift register).  Mersenne twister itself needs too much memory for microcontrollers.

The problem with these generators is that they may generate long sequences near zero if you are unlucky. With a reasonable size of the state space and initialization from another PNRG this is however unlikely.

They are also not secure for cryptography or gambling, an intelligent adversary can predict future states after observing the output. This is because they are linear.

I once designed such a generator for a small nonstandard processor with a state space of about 50 24-bit words. I tested variants with the Diehard test suite until I found a good one. The application was generating random variations for a hardware test.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the timer and xoring/nanding/etc it with a series of bits will give a semi random to the user, as the timing between events is likely to be enough apart that the user won't really be able to tell the correlation with the timer.

Answer (score -1):

If you can leave a pin floating, it could help to generate random numbers with *linear feedback shift register*. I'm not sure this is the way to go, but please have a look at my code:

```
// This code was written for 8051 (AT89S52)
unsigned char lfsr = 231; //8 bit shift register, with the seed of 231 or '11100111b'
unsigned char input_bit, i;

void main (void) 
{
    //Setup
    P0_0 = 0; // Leave Pin 0 Port 0 floating
    uart_init(); //Initializing uart/serial communication with pc


    while (1) 
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 255; i++) 
        {
            if (P0_0 == 1) // If Pin 0.0 is HIGH
            {
                input_bit = ((lfsr >> 0) ^ (lfsr >> 2) ^ (lfsr >> 3) ^ (lfsr >> 4)) & 1;
                lfsr = (lfsr >> 1) | (input_bit << 7);
            }
        }
        printf_tiny("%u\n", lfsr); //Send the random number to PC
        soft_delay(65535); //Simple delay function
    } //end while (1) loop

}
```

**EDIT:** I found out my answer may be a bad one. More details on why should not use a floating digital pin: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/50476/random-number-generators-using-a-gpio-pin