# Implement timer in PIC18F for random number generation

Tags: c, timer, pic, pic18

There has been a lot of time since I don't post anything here. Today I came here looking for help to implement a timer in a PIC18F microcontroller. I want this timer to be used for using it as seed for the srand() function...but after searching a lot here I couldn't find a way to solve this problem.

Would you help me, please.

Thanks from a newbe.

Comment: Up to now, what I have its a Timer when the program is started. After I do some setup configuration, I ask the user to push a button. When he push a button, I recover the time from that timer and put it as seed in the srand.
However, what I was interested in, was in not making the user press any button. Is there any possible way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem in need of a very complex thing. No interrupts etc. Start a timer and just at an arbitrary point of code read timer value then feed it into srand.

```
 srand(aTimeFunctionYouWrite()); // random seed USE ONCE...
```

now your rand() accesses are randomized.

In the peripheral library of C18 you can find functions and definitions needed.
You can use them via

```
 #include <timers.h>
```

And look at the doc folder for documentation.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for the answer. Thats more or less what I have. I have a Timer that is started at the beginning of the program. At some point I ask the user to press a button. At that time I recover the value from the Timer and use it as srand argument.
However, I was looking forward not to making the user press anything. So that TimeFunctionYouWrite(), is there any possible way to do it without user interaction??

By the way, I am using XC8 :)

Thank you! :)

Comment: Here is a lead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558321/how-do-i-generate-random-numbers-in-a-microcontroller-efficiently